# Box-shadow on table row hides "under" next row when next row is colored

Tags: html, css, html-table, background-color, border-box

Using the following source code, I have two problems :

1. as is, the bottom shadow do not appear, except on the last row

   [image]
   [image]
2. if I transfer the `background-color:white;` statement from the `TD` element to the `TR` element, then the shadow works everywhere, except on the one before the row containing the 'special' DIV.

   [image]
   [image]

It would be very difficult to change the way the app I'm working on constructs the table, so I can't move the special1 and special2 classes from the DIVs.

How may I do to make this highlight work in any situation ?

**Source code**

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<HEAD>
<STYLE>
TR {
    line-height: 15px;
    background-color:white;
}

TD {    
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: #333;
    height: inherit;
}

DIV.special1 {
    background-color:orange;
    float:left;
}

DIV.special2 {
    background-color:red;
}

TD.highlighted, TR.highlighted {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #333333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #333333;
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #333333;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #333333;
}
</STYLE>

<SCRIPT>
function highlight(id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id).className.indexOf("highlighted") == -1) document.getElementById(id).className += "highlighted";
}

function unhighlight(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).className = document.getElementById(id).className.replace("highlighted", "");
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<TABLE width="200" BORDER="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<TR><TD id="1" onmouseover="highlight(1);" onmouseout="unhighlight(1);"><DIV>test test test</DIV></TD></TR>
<TR><TD id="2" onmouseover="highlight(2);" onmouseout="unhighlight(2);"><DIV>test test test</DIV></TD></TR>
<TR><TD id="3" onmouseover="highlight(3);" onmouseout="unhighlight(3);"><DIV>test test test</DIV></TD></TR>
<TR><TD id="4" onmouseover="highlight(4);" onmouseout="unhighlight(4);"><DIV class="special1">test test test</DIV><DIV class="special2">test test test</DIV></TD></TR>
<TR><TD id="5" onmouseover="highlight(5);" onmouseout="unhighlight(5);"><DIV>test test test</DIV></TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: This is a pure guess, hence why it's not an answer, but you could make the `z-index` higher when the box shadow is applied. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add relative positioning to the `.highlighted` element [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/ax46c8fu/)

```
td.highlighted, tr.highlighted {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #333333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #333333;
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #333333;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #333333;
  position: relative;
}
```